# Printed variable changes position of character

Tags: python, symbols

I am coding a game project and am going through the code to finish up some small bugs and features in the code. I am having a problem with trying to print out the users stats in graphical box made up of text symbols.
*Here is the code*

```
print ("⚜================== Player 1 City ==================⚜")
print ("⚜BaseHP  =  " + str (p1_basehp))
print ("⚜Troops  =  " + str (p1_troops))
print ("⚜Archers =  " + str (p1_archers))
print ("⚜Food    =  " + str (p1_food))
print ("⚜===================================================⚜")
```

When the code is run in the game it looks like this.

```
⚜================== Player 1 City ==================⚜
⚜BaseHP  =  1000
⚜Troops  =  20
⚜Archers =  30
⚜Food    =  500
⚜===================================================⚜
```

But I would really like to have the users stats in a box, like this.

```
⚜================== Player 1 City ==================⚜
⚜BaseHP  =  1000                                    ⚜
⚜Troops  =  20                                      ⚜
⚜Archers =  30                                      ⚜
⚜Food    =  500                                     ⚜
⚜===================================================⚜
```

It's picky I know, but I want to do a full job of the game and not just leave bits in the game looking unfinished. The problem is that the 4 lists change value through out the game depending on the users actions so they cannot be predicted, this means that when the values are printed out the symbols on the right side of the box aren't in line. How do I keep the character in the same place no matter what the 4 lists p1_basehp, p1_troops, p1_archers and p1_food are. 
**There is no error in the code it is just a query.**

Comment: I've written a module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dosbox-screen/) that makes such tasks easier. You can use it directly (it also works on *nix) or look at the implementation (line 375-end of screen.py would be relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why make it so complicated? Just use the standard string formatting substitutions with a specified width:

```
print ("⚜================== Player 1 City ==================⚜")
print ("⚜ %-7s = %-39d ⚜" % ("BaseHP", p1_basehp))
print ("⚜ %-7s = %-39d ⚜" % ("Troops", p1_troops))
etc.
```

Or if you'll align the labels yourself:

```
print("⚜BaseHP  = %-39d ⚜" % p1_basehp)
etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) to do this with padding and align options.

```
In [120]: p1 = 1
In [121]: p2 = 123
In [122]: p3 = 12345
In [123]: print "** BaseHP  =  " + '{:10}'.format(str(p1)) + '*'
In [124]: print "** BaseHP  =  " + '{:10}'.format(str(p2)) + '*'
In [125]: print "** BaseHP  =  " + '{:10}'.format(str(p3)) + '*'
```

OUTPUT:

```
** BaseHP  =  1         *
** BaseHP  =  123       *
** BaseHP  =  12345     *
```

Though the len of variable changes the overall alignment remains same.

Comment: you can  shorten even more `print "⚜ {:7} ={:10}⚜".format('BaseHP', str(p1))`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have fixed length for the first part of each stat line (12 characters) and your header takes 53 characters, you need to place 39 blank spaces before the ending character `⚜` if your value has just one digit, 38 if two digits, ...and so on. I,e: `' '*(40 - len(str(p1_<whatever>)))`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from random import randint

p1_archers = randint(1, 1000)
p1_basehp = randint(1, 1000)
p1_food = randint(1, 1000)
p1_troops = randint(1, 1000)

print ("⚜================== Player 1 City ==================⚜")
print ("⚜BaseHP  =  " + str (p1_basehp)) + ' '*(40 - len(str(p1_basehp))) + '⚜'
print ("⚜Troops  =  " + str (p1_troops)) + ' '*(40 - len(str(p1_troops))) + '⚜'
print ("⚜Archers =  " + str (p1_archers)) + ' '*(40 - len(str(p1_archers))) + '⚜'
print ("⚜Food    =  " + str (p1_food)) + ' '*(40 - len(str(p1_food))) + '⚜'
print ("⚜===================================================⚜")
```

Note: I make use of `random` library to proof proper functionality with different scenarios:

```
⚜===================================================⚜
[Vostro-3350 workspace]$ python so.py 
⚜================== Player 1 City ==================⚜
⚜BaseHP  =  846                                     ⚜
⚜Troops  =  334                                     ⚜
⚜Archers =  685                                     ⚜
⚜Food    =  94                                      ⚜
⚜===================================================⚜
[Vostro-3350 workspace]$ python so.py 
⚜================== Player 1 City ==================⚜
⚜BaseHP  =  70                                      ⚜
⚜Troops  =  8                                       ⚜
⚜Archers =  306                                     ⚜
⚜Food    =  411                                     ⚜
⚜===================================================⚜
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is make that many space extra as the difference of `=` is bottom line and lenght of that str value.

```
print ("⚜BaseHP  =  " + str (p1_basehp),' '*(40 - len(str(p1_basehp))),'*')
print ("⚜Troops  =  " + str (p1_troops),' '*(40 - len(str(p1_troops))),'*')
print ("⚜Archers =  " + str (p1_archers),' '*(40 - len(str(p1_archers))),'*')
print ("⚜Food    =  " + str (p1_food),' '*(40 - len(str(p1_food))),'*')
print ("⚜===================================================⚜")
```